# Run jScrollPane styling After InfoBox has opened

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3, jscrollpane, infowindow, jquery-jscrollpane

I would like to style a div with the jScrollPane program, but the issue is that the div is within an infobox that first needs to be initialized before the div can be styled. How can I achieve this?

```
var infoBox1Settings = {
        content: boxText
    ,disableAutoPan: false
    ,alignBottom: true
    ,maxWidth: 0
    ,pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-142, -28)
    ,zIndex: null
    ,closeBoxMargin: ''
    ,closeBoxURL: ''
    ,infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1)
    ,isHidden: false
    ,pane: 'floatPane'
    ,enableEventPropagation: false
};

infowindowVenue = new InfoBox(infoBox1Settings);
infowindowVenue.open(map, markersHash['markerVenue'+data.id]);

var searchElement = $(".venue-prof").jScrollPane({showArrows: true});
searchApi = searchElement.data('jsp');
```

Comment: You want to attach JSP to .venue-prof div, but .venue-prof couldn't be generated yet by another script?

Comment: Yes. .venue-prof is generated after infobox opens a window on Google Maps.

Answer (score 2):

observe the domready-event of the infobox and apply the jScrollPane when it fires:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(infowindowVenue ,'domready',function(){
   $('.venue-prof',this.div_).jScrollPane({showArrows: true});
});
```

Comment: Thanks Dr. Molle! I'm getting this error now: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'domready' of undefined